# Calculate ClientX/ClientY position on touch events for Mobile/Tablets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to place a context menu (right click menu) next to where a user clicks or touches. It works great on the web because I can get the clientX/clientY positions of the click event. However, with touch events on a tablet (iPad specifically), only event.x, event.y are available, which will not work when there is a lot of scroll because the context menu will append outside of the viewport. How can I calculate clientX/clientY values on mobile/tablet devices?

```js
            $(document).on("contextmenu doubletap", '.table', function (event) {
                console.log('right click event');
                var menu = $(this).find('.custom-menu');
                console.log(event);
                // Avoid the real one
                event.preventDefault();
                // Show contextmenu
                menu.finish().toggle(100).
                // In the right position (the mouse)n
                css({
                    //position of mouse click on computer/ipad
                    top: (event.clientY) + "px",
                    left: (event.clientX) + "px"
                });
            });
```

Comment: take a look at  [touch.clientX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/clientX)

Comment: @Taki awesome thank you! Works for me since i'll be using Chrome only for this project, but do you know of a cross browser solution for mobile?